Please help me understand this problem about cardinality
Me and my friend are in the process of creating an ER diagram for a professional soccer league, we are both very new to Database so we aren't sure if everything we do is correct.
When creating a relationship between a manager and a club, he made this: 
I'm quite confused about why the 2 relationships managedBy and signsWith are Many to Many. My friend said that multiple managers can manage multiple clubs, one-on-one at a time. But shouldn't that be One to One instead? Since at any moment in time, a club can only have a single manager managing it and a manager can only have a single club to manage (we do not care about assistant manager in this instance); same thing about the signsWith relationship.
So which one of us is right?


My friend said that multiple managers can manage multiple clubs, one-on-one at a time. But shouldn't that be One to One instead? Since at any moment in time, a club can only have a single manager managing it and a manager can only have a single club to manage (we do not care about assistant manager in this instance); same thing about the signsWith relationship.

This is more of a word problem and conceptual problem, than a database problem.
Your friend is probably thinking in regards to if history is kept. E.g. Club A is created, Manager 1 manages it, actively. Then one day switches to manage Club B. In your friend's mine, the table will still have the history of when Manager 1 used to manage Club A, even if he's not actively their manager anymore.
So it really depends on if you guys need that history. Though I would store something like that in a separate table (usually something like a Transactions table keeps track of that stuff), or use some form of change tracking for history, and not in the same table as the active managers. In which case, it would be a one-to-one relationship in your active managers table.
